# Running app from Android Studio on One Plus X not working

Tags: android, android-studio, drivers

I have done all the process which is mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) to install USB Driver for One plus x. When installing USB driver from the location "Android sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\" it is showing that "Windows couldn't find driver software for your device" [image]

Can someone tell me the solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable the development settings on the phone? I could just connect using the driver delivered by Oneplus on the phone itself. Installed those and after enabling the development settings the device showed up in Android Studio.